# How do I change the business email address for a Facebook Page I created?

Tags: facebook-pages

I need help changing my email address on my `Facebook Page`. It is currently set to my personal email address and I want it to be the business email address. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can change the email address on a Facebook Page by doing the following:

Instructions if Timeline for Pages hasn't been implemented yet (The old look)

1. Go to your page while logged into Facebook
2. Click the `Edit Page` button in the upper right below the Facebook bar
3. Click `Basic Information`
4. At the bottom of the page edit the `email` field
5. Click `Save Changes`

Instructions if Timeline for Pages HAS been implemented for your page

1. Go to your page
2. You may have to click the `Admin Panel` button to the right of the cover photo
3. Once the `Admin Panel` is open click the `Edit Page` button
4. Click `Update Info`
5. Click `Basic Information`
6. At the bottom of the page edit the `email` field
7. Click `Save Changes`

Comment: I'm one of the admin/manager for https://www.facebook.com/ReturnToKgPenarik . However, I failed to find the `email` field on its `Basic Information` admin page. Did something change since your answer, Dez?

Comment: I have just updated the steps to my question based on how to currently get to the basic information screen.

Comment: Thanks for the update, Dez. I did get to that `Admin Panel > Edit page > Update Info > Basic Information` earlier. But I don't see email field at all there. [Screenshot of that basic info page](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2542993/returntokgpenarik-no-email.png).

Comment: This doesn't work: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/56859/why-is-facebook-complaining-about-my-company-email-address

Answer (score 1):

> To change your login email address:
>
> 1. Open the Account dropdown menu at the top right corner of Facebook and choose **Account Settings**.
> 2. Click the [Edit](http://www.facebook.com/help/settings?tab=account&section=email&t) link next to Email.
> 3. Click **Add another email**.
> 4. Type your new email address in the open field and click **Save Changes**.
> 5. You will be asked to **enter your password** for security purposes.
> 6. You will then be sent a confirmation email to the new email address. You will not be able to log in with the new address until it is confirmed.
>
> **Note**:
>
> - Any of the email addresses associated with your account can be used as login email addresses.
> - If you are having trouble accessing an existing account on the site, please do not create another account, as this is a violation of our Terms of Use and may delay resolution of the issue.

From the [Facebook help page](http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=162801153783275).

Answer (score 0):

Not at this time. You'll receive Page email notifications at the primary email address connected with your personal account.

http://www.facebook.com/help/255700674532721/

Comment: To improve this answer, I would add the text of the relevant portions of the help article you are referencing. What happens if the article moves or changes and the link becomes obsolete?