# Remove an email address used to create a Facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I created a Facebook Business page with my personal email address but want to remove that and use my business email for the account alone.

In hindsight, I should have used a business email address.  I've gone through and [changed the email address in the Admin Panel](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/24616/how-do-i-change-the-business-email-address-for-a-facebook-page-i-created)

The new work email logs right into the Business Facebook page. If I log out and try logging in with the personal email address, it also still goes to the page.  I appear now to have two email addresses going to that Business page.

I'd like to permanently remove the personal one so I can create a personal Facebook profile.

Answer (score 1):

Each Facebook Page (brand concept) is administered by one and more flesh-and-blood human beings who have created themselves a personal Facebook Profile:   there is no such thing as a personal and a business profile in Facebook, by definition all Profiles are personal.

Now it may be possible to fool Facebook into creating a Profile for a business, but don't waste your time:  you are are simply inviting them to delete it once they discover it - for example, when one of your competitors reports it.

Taking a step back, why you are wanting to use the business email for the Facebook - is it because you want to give the password to someone else so that they can also maintain it?   If so, then you need to

1. Get their agreement (off-line) to administer the page
2. Get them to use their personal Profile to Like the page Look at the
   list of people who have Liked your page
3. Choose the person from it, and make them into an administrator.

I know this isn't the answer you want to hear:  it's distinctly strange that your business needs to make use of artifacts from people's personal lives to update its communication tools.   But I'm afraid that's the way Facebook works, today anyway.