# Why is Facebook complaining about my company email address?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-profile

When I try to add an email address to Facebook, it says 'invalid'. But it's not!

[minus http://i.minus.com/ibd3lFKGnq5s4x.png](http://i.minus.com/ibd3lFKGnq5s4x.png)

Comment: Do you have a space before the `@`?

Comment: @AlE. No. I don't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Facebook [says](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10200304769357838):

> Unfortunately, we don't support email addresses with generic prefixes
>   like info@, webmaster@, etc. Since email addresses of this nature are
>   typically used for organizations and businesses, we don't allow them
>   to be used for personal Facebook accounts. Please try signing up again
>   using another address that you own.

Of course they should have explained this when you tried your info@ email address. Bad UX.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense, because I DO own that email, and of course it is for a business. WalMart has a Facebook page, why can't my business? When you first sign up for Facebook, it asks for your First Name, Last Name, gender, age, etc. There IS no option for a company!

Comment: You want to create a page or a user account?

Comment: A Facebook page for the company web site.

Comment: A Facebook page must be created from a user account.

Comment: Wow that is odd. So the CEOs of companies are creating Facebook pages?

Comment: Yep (or more likely some community manager or marketing folk). https://www.facebook.com/pages/create/

Comment: Facebook only wants *real people* create accounts. Nothing else.